# Не могу подключиться к kafka из docker контейнера

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-kafka

Запускаю сервисы, а также kafka и zookeeper в контейнерах докер.

Запускаю сервис akhq , который являются как бы панелью для просмотра топиков и сообщений кафка.

В сервисе akhq отображаются созданные топики и сообщения kafka. этот сервис подключается по адресу kafka:9092

Но другой сервис adapter , не может подключиться к кафке.
Получает ошибку: dial tcp :9092: connect: connection refused

Хотя  сервис adapter также пытается подключается к kafka:9092 , (пробовал и 127.0.0.1:9092 и localhost:9092)
Из консоли сервиса adapter адрес kafka:9092 успешно пингуется.

Как можно исправить?

Прикладываю docker-compose.yaml

```html
version: '3'

volumes:
  zookeeper-data:
    driver: local
  zookeeper-log:
    driver: local
  kafka-data:
    driver: local

services:
    akhq:
        image: tchiotludo/akhq
        environment: 
          AKHQ_CONFIGURATION: |
            akhq:
              security:
                default-group: reader
              connections:
                docker-kafka-server:
                  properties:
                    bootstrap.servers: "kafka:9092"
                  schema-registry:
                    url: "http://schema-registry:8085"

        ports:
          - 8888:8080
        links:
          - kafka
          - schema-registry

    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
        volumes:
          - zookeeper-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data:Z
          - zookeeper-log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log:Z
        environment:
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: '2181'
          ZOOKEEPER_ADMIN_ENABLE_SERVER: 'false'

    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
        volumes:
          - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data:Z
        environment:
          KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '0'
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
          KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: '12'
          KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE: 'gzip'
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
          KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
          KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: '1'
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092'
          KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
          KAFKA_JMX_PORT: '9091'
          KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
          KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: 'kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer'
          KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
        links:
          - zookeeper

    schema-registry:
        image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
        depends_on:
          - kafka
        environment:
          SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092'
          SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: 'schema-registry'
          SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: 'http://0.0.0.0:8085'
          SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: 'INFO'


    adapter: #kafka adapter
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./adapter.dockerfile
        environment:
            - GO_ENV=dev
            - GOPATH=/go
        container_name: kafka-adapter-app
        depends_on:
          - kafka
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь ошибка

```
services:
    akhq:
        image: tchiotludo/akhq
        ....
        links:
          - kafka
          - schema-registry
```

`links` не создаёт зависимости между сервисами. Надо использовать `depends_on`, тогда `docker compose` дождётся Кафки, а потом уже запустит `akhq`

Answer (score 0):

суть в том , что сервис при запуске сразу пытается подключиться к Кафке.
Kafka в этот момент ещё не готова к работе.

Поставил сервису тайм-аут от запуска сервис до попытки подключения.